# how can I copy elements after selected them in inkcanavas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, copy-paste, inkcanvas

I tried to use `Inkcanvas.copy()`and `Inkcanvas.Paste()` but it failed so I save the elements in list and then tried to add them again as a child in the `inkcanvas` but I got exception error

> Specified Visual is already a child of
>   another Visual or the root of a
>   CompositionTarget.

so what should I do ?

Comment: Well, that message means that your elements can't belong to multiple parents.  Copy and Paste are probably more what you want.  What problem did you have using them?

Comment: Do you want to duplicate the children?

Comment: yes I want to duplicate the children

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the selected element(when copying) using XamlWriter.Save, and de-serialize/load(when Pasting) using XamlReader.Load. But there are issues with serializing and de-serializing using XamlReader/XamlWriter which you will have to take care of(you can find a lot of help regarding that on SO and web).

You can have a look at this article having this implementation for Custom Canvas -

[WPF Diagram Designer - Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx)